# Is there any way to use a stored entity to call a method?

Tags: java, entity, instance

I'm rather new to the programming lingo, basic terms I can understand but as of yet a lot flies over my head so please try to keep things simple.
I'm trying to use an entity(I believe that's what you call it), to call a method. So for example, if I had dog1 as an instance of the object Dog, and Dog had the variable dogID. Now if I initialised the instance and set the only variable that is (String) dogID for instance dog1 to A001 with:
Dog dog1 = new Dog{"A001"};

now if I use substring and Integer.parseInt() to select the three numeric characters and translate them into an int value and set it to int intTemp (the output would be 1, or if it was 094 it would be 94), and I wanted to use this:
String temp = "owner" + intTemp;

meaning
System.out.println(temp);

would show:
owner1

Is there any way I could use this entity of owner1 to call a method of owner1, say owner1.displayAll(); ?

My entire reasoning for this is to avoid having to write and duplicate methods for every possible instance of the Owner object i.e. owner1 all the way through to owner999.

If anyone has any ideas or thoughts, it'd be great to hear them.
Thank you.

Comment: It would help if we had a little more description as to what the data structure is in this case. As far as I can tell, there is an object Dog and an object Owner? Is the owner object contained within the dog object? If not, how it is created? Code in these cases sometimes helps

Comment: I'll hop to it when I'm home. Struggling with my laptop on a bus, both objects are seperate and are not related through child-parent relations. My whole curiosity is about using an entity to call a method, for example you couldn't just do temp.displayAll(); because it would try to find a method related to the temp, which isn't an instance in the first place so it'd never work.

Comment: Ahhh ok. I misunderstood the question a little bit. The way you have described it, getting owner1 from a function and then calling owner1.function from somewhere when owner1 is from a string will not work unfortunately. It would have to be a key from a dictionary or something like that

Comment: So there's no way to make it work at all? It'd be mighty handy if there was a way around it

Comment: What exactly is your goal? To be able to dynamically access an object based on the value returned from a function in an unrelated object with the assumption that both objects already exist?

Comment: basically yes, this was all based around a rather basic vet system for registering pets with their owners. I wanted to use IDs that partially matched, allowing me to link owner with pets solely through the link in their IDs. I know how to link them otherwise, but this idea seemed interesting to me so I figured I'd pursue it! Thanks for the rundown my friend

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Map to store all owners with their corresponding ids it could look like this:

```
Map<String, Owner> ownerMap = new HashMap<>();
ownerMap.put("owner1", owner);
```

And then to get the owner:

```
ownerMap.get("owner1");
```

Comment: What exceptions are thrown and where?